# Как перехватывать и модифицировать видеопоток с вебкамеры?

Tags: windows, directshow, видео

Привет, it-guru!

У меня задача. Модифицировать видео поток с веб-камеры прозрачно для приложений. Например, включаете вы условный вебкамрекордер, а на видео записываетесь вы, но без штанов :). Слышал, что для OS Windows есть  DirectShow и некие DirectShow-фильтры, но я в этом совершенно не специалист.

Собственно вопросы.

Для всех ли камер такой финт возможен? Сопряжена ли подобная разработка со страшными мучениями или много ли крови потребует изучение API? Как такое делать на других платформах, например, Ubuntu, Android?

Буду благодарен за любой полезный совет. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Насчёт директшоу. Использовать его достаточно несложно, а вот фильтры - там много хитростей всяких .-. Но, благо, документация имеется подробная и примеры тоже (Windows SDK, multimedia\directshow) - там и фильтры есть, и много всякого другого. Захват видео с камеры тоже есть - для проверки.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что сие не так то просто реализовать.

Comment: Ну, принципиально модифицировать видеопоток не так и трудно. Инвертировать цвет, например или сделать серым - это влёт оно сделает. Что мне не очень понятно - как заставить программы создавать граф с дополнительным преобразующим фильтром (ну, подгружать его автоматически) в середине, ну и алгоритмы достаточно быстрые для анализа и коррекции видеопотока - то есть найти объект на картинке и подменить его чем-то иным =) Видео ждать не будет)

Comment: Если отбросить сложность алгоритма преобразования, имеется в виду, что можно только стандартный фильтр подключить, а самодеятельность нельзя вкорячить для всех программ, подключающихся к камере?

Comment: Не, имеется в виду, что если и можно - то любой преобразующий видео фильтр туда встанет (конечно, если фильтры совместимы по входным и выходным параметрам видео - т.е. должны поддерживаться ещё и разные цветовые модели). Интерфейсы у фильтров одни и те же и сложный фильтр отличается от простого только внутренностями. DirectVobSub - пример фильтра, который умеет автоматически подгружаться (но не в вин7) при воспроизведении видео в плеере с помощью DS и системных кодеков... (но внутренности там ужасны)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать некое подобие driver-proxy, в системе определяется виртуальная камера, которая эмулирует обычную камеру, но берет данные как посредник с настоящей камеры и обрабатывает как надо.

насколько я понимаю, автор пытается реализовать подмену изображения для видео-чатов или чего-то аналогичного )

http://www.manycam.com/
Это не то что нужно?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Эта прога наверное делает то, что я хочу, чтоб делала моя прога.

Comment: Для Linux аналогичное - v4l2loopback

Answer (score 0):

Есть замечательный набор библиотек OpenCV. Правда он заточен под системы компьютерного зрения, но довольно не сложен в освоении и имеет широкие возможности по обработке изображений (в том числе и видео потоков). А захват с камеры - так это вообще пара строк. Если заинтересует, могу привести примеры и что почитать. Тороплюсь сейчас просто. Вообще штука кроссплатформенная. Начиная с версии 2.2 - поддержка Android.

Comment: Обработку-то я и собирался с OpenCV делать, поскольку с другим не знаком. А как подсунуть результат приложениям?

Comment: А о каом подсовывании идет речь? Какова роль самого приложения?

Comment: Устроит отдельное окно с обработанным видео?

Comment: Насколько я понял - для любого приложения ничего не должно поменятся в плане использования камерой. Но только вот видеопоток должен попасть уже изменённым.

Comment: именно